# Where can I find a Python method to clearly and concisely initialize lists?

Tags: python, list, function

Creating lists is a very common task for me, and when those lists need to be initialized, the Python code needed to do so feels overly complex and low level. I would like to find a method something like this:

```py
def create_list(size = 0, initial_value = None, initializer = None):
    """
    Creates a list of the specified `size`.
    If `initial_value` is specified, then all elements will be assigned that value.
    If `initializer` is specified, it is assumed to be a callable (function or lambda)
      and will be called for each element, passing to it the array index.
    If both `initial_value` and `initializer` are specified, an error is raised.
    """
```

How can I implement this, and am I duplicating a similar method elsewhere in the Python ecosystem?

Comment: You probably cannot find this because you can just use a list comprehension.

Comment: There is no need for a function which does e.g. `17 * [4]` or even `[init(i) for i in range(6)]`. Having a function do that would just make the code less readable.

Comment: The list comprehension is lower level, i.e. instructions to the machine as opposed to a higher level human-oriented description that my function provides. I get that this is subjective though and although I prefer the latter, others would not.

Comment: It would be simple to write your own Class which does exactly what you want and gives you a List initialized in either of the two ways and that you can then use just as a basic Python List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think having one "catch all" `create_list` function which can *either* use an initializer or an initial value isn't good design. These should be two functions: One that uses an initial value and one that uses an initializer.

Using Python's builtin `*` (list repetition), the first one is reasonably concise (and efficient):

- `[None] * size`
- `[initial_value] * size`

For the second one, I'd just use `list(map(initializer, range(size)))`. In the special (yet common) case of `initializer = lambda x: x`, this simplifies to `list(range(size))`. It might indeed be reasonable to define a function to shorten the former:

```py
def make_list(size, initializer):
    return list(map(initializer, range(size)))
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I am new to Python and did not realize that all the cases I wanted to handle had implementations as simple and concise as the ones you posted.

Comment: Also, good point about using two methods instead of one.

Comment: What would you name these functions? The best I could come up with was "create_list_with_value" and "create_list_with_initializer".

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find this method in various libraries I've researched, so I wrote my own and may include it and other similar functions in an open source library (feel free to suggest a library, etc.):

```py
def create_list(size = 0, initial_value = None, initializer = None):
    """
    Creates a list of the specified `size`.
    If `initial_value` is specified, then all elements will be assigned that value.
    If `initializer` is specified, it is assumed to be a callable (function or lambda)
      and will be called for each element, passing to it the array index.
    If both `initial_value` and `initializer` are specified, that is an error.
    """
    if size < 0:
        raise ValueError("Size cannot be negative.")
    if initial_value is not None and initializer is not None:
        raise ValueError("Specifying both initial_value and initializer is not permitted.")
    elif initial_value is not None:
        return [initial_value for _ in range(size)]
    elif initializer is not None:
        return [initializer(i) for i in range(size)]
    else:
        return [None for _ in range(size)]
```

Test code is:

```py
import unittest
from create_list import create_list

class TestCreateList(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_create_list_with_no_arguments(self):
        self.assertEqual(create_list(), [])

    def test_create_list_with_nonzero_size(self):
        self.assertEqual(create_list(2), [None, None])

    def test_negative_size(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            create_list(-1)

    def test_create_list_zero_size(self):
        self.assertEqual(create_list(0), [])

    def test_create_list_non_integer(self):
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            create_list('five')

    def test_create_list_with_initial_value(self):
        size = 4
        value = 'foo'
        result = create_list(size, initial_value = value)
        self.assertEqual(result, size * [value])

    def test_create_list_with_initial_value_and_initializer(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            create_list(1, initial_value = 1, initializer = lambda x: x)

    def test_initializer(self):
        size = 2
        result = create_list(size, initializer = lambda x: f"Element {x}")
        self.assertEqual(result, ["Element 0", "Element 1"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: What stops you from just using the respective [native] list comprehension, that function returns, instead of adding this function to any project you want to use it in (even if you package it in some sort of helper/utilities package)?

Comment: @buran I am new to Python and was not aware that this could be accomplished as simply as Luatic showed below. I do think my function (or 2 as Luatic suggested) is more intuitive, and wish there were one like it in the language, but I get that adding it to a library or application might not be a good idea.